# How to change font color for method names (from yellow) in the new Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have updated to the newest Visual Studio 2019 and it looks like they have changed color scheme for text, e.g. method names became yellow. I would like to return it back to white as before, but can't figure out where this setting is.

P.S. Same thing for parameter names that became blue. There is probably some option to switch to old color scheme?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

VS2019 also introduced new "enhanced" colors for .NET languages, for which there is a separate option to toggle on and off:

[image: Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C# -> Advanced, "Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic" setting]

The same checkbox is listed for both C# and Basic (VB).

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks :) I suppose this options turns off these colors that I have edited manually

Comment: Thanks a lot! This has saved me.

Comment: You're a life savor

Comment: This have been changed in recently. You'll find it under same place but it has become a drop down menu called 'Editor Color Scheme' - then select 'Visual Studio 2017' on the drop down menu to get the old color scheme back.

Answer (score 31):

Updated answer for 2020.

[image: Visual Studio 2019 color scheme]

Make sure this is set to 2019.

Comment: Yes, indeed! This is now (2020) the solution! Version of VS: 16.6.1

Comment: Yes. This is the solution now.

Comment: @ValiMaties apparently not anymore. The equivalent thing for C++ is missing. For C# too. I just checked.

Comment: @aalimian I use version 16.9.0 Preview 2.0 and it is there, I don't know what version you use! BTW, I always update my VS.

Comment: @ValiMaties, please take a look at my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228947/how-to-disable-vs2019s-syntax-coloring-for-c-and-make-it-look-like-vs2017

Comment: @aalimian , in your comment you wrote "The equivalent thing for C++ is missing". I don't know this, I'm not a C/C++ programmer. But you also wrote "For C# too". 
My response was to this affirmation, because it is not true. The option is there, that ComboList is there! Please look here: https://i.ibb.co/vhqQxH4/Option-Exists.jpg It was made 2 minutes ago (2020.12.11 20:49:20)

Comment: @ValiMaties, you have the Community Preview, I have the VS2019 Professional. And for C# I don't see it unfortunately. Maybe this is something available in Preview.

Comment: Used to work great till today. Not entirely sure what caused it.

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to change in `Options->Environment->Fonts and Colors`. There is a list with different `User Memebers - ...` and `User Tyeps - ...` that define these colors.

[image]

I have actually changed `User Members - Fields` and `User Members - Properties` to be same color as `User Member - Parameters`. It became much better, white and yellow did not work too well for me :)

Now it's almost like Visual Studio Code

Comment: Works even if color scheme (from @Zoidbergseasharp) is default (2019).

Answer (score 0):

If you are coding in C++ you probably have enhanced color activate. To deactivate go Tool-->Options and from the left menu select Text Editor-->C/C++-->View. Then go to the section "Miscellaneous" on the right and change "Color Scheme" from "Enhanced" to "Visual Studio 2017"

Comment: This setting has apparently disappeared. I have the latest updated version Visual Studio 2019 Professional and it's not there. really disappointing.