# Restore editor colours from VS 2017 in VS2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've recently installed Vsiaul Studio 2019 and I notice the colour scheme has changed since VS2017, both of the shell and the editor window. How can I restore the editor colours from VS 2017?

Comment: Is this the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514898/how-to-change-font-color-for-method-names-from-yellow-in-the-new-visual-studio?

Comment: @Jimmy I think so. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change font color for method names (from yellow) in the new Visual Studio 2019?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514898/how-to-change-font-color-for-method-names-from-yellow-in-the-new-visual-studio)

Comment: Have you tried exporting the colours settings from VS2017 and importing into VS2019?

Answer (score 4):

Even though it is a duplicate of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514898/how-to-change-font-color-for-method-names-from-yellow-in-the-new-visual-studio), You can simply achieve this by navigating through the following : `Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced` then under the `Clarifications` section uncheck the `Use enhanced colors` option.

**Note that C# can be any other language that you are using since Visual Studio does not allow changing this option for all languages.**