# How can you change text color settings in Visual Studio 2019 to match the style of VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio

I am not talking about theme.  What I mean is the following:

[image: Side by side]
Left: VS2017, Right: VS2019.

I tried to export VS2017 settings and import them into 2019 but it appears that options available in 2019 aren't present in 2017 that change the palette around.

I am looking to be able to assist not only me, but the rest of my team in changing these settings to mimic VS2017 as easily as possible.

Aside from finding and manually changing each these of these settings individually is there a better way to more or less all at once revert the text color scheme back to the way it was in VS2017?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55514898/how-to-change-font-color-for-method-names-from-yellow-in-the-new-visual-studio

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can revert to the 2017 style by disabling Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Use enhanced colors for C# and Basic.

Comment: These days its a dropdown in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Advanced > Editor Color Scheme. You can select Visual Studio 2017 there. I Had to do this to get SemanticColorizer to work. It was overridden by VS 2019 color scheme.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have 2019 to see what the differences are, but the approach I'd take is to have one person go through the process of customizing the colors to 2017 ones, then export the settings to a file that your peers can then import (in 2017 this is under Tools > Import and Export Settings).

I'm curious why you want to see a specific color theme across the team.

Comment: I'm not imposing a specific color on the team.  My team members and I have all expressed dissatisfaction with the default color scheme in 2019.  Everything is colorful to the point of uselessness and I told the team I'd look for a solution.  I'm attempting a few things to try to resolve this for us but figure if someone else has a better way this question might find me that answer.

That being said I like your idea.  Thank you.

Comment: Thank you,a nd you're welcome. - I've softened the language about my question about motivation (must have been in a bad mood that day ;-)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is caused by the extension called Javascript and Typescript Nightly. This is causing the syntax highlighting for js and ts files (jsx and tax too). This is more of a bug with the latest version(Currently 1.73.1).

You can disable the extension to enable the syntax highlighting.