# How to disable VS2019's syntax coloring for C++ and make it look like VS2017

Tags: c++, themes, visual-studio-2019, syntax-highlighting

I'm a light theme user, and I guess that makes me unpopular, but I'm sure there are still some light theme users out there. I have switched to VS2019 and the light theme (called Blue Theme) was a nightmare. It turned out it was an issue and the solution can be found in [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/401029/new-vs2019-blue-theme-feels-a-little-too-lightpale.html?inRegister=true).

My other question is the C++ syntax coloring in VS2019. It's just too many colors and makes it really hard for the eyes (once again if using the light theme).

I have looked but don't know where can I disable this new fancy syntax coloring and go back to VS2017's syntax coloring in VS2019. Any tips?

Here's a screenshot of what I have in VS2019:
[image]

I think it's a bit too much. I don't wanna see purple, green, red and brown.

As per this [Microsoft link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/ide/how-to-set-preferences?view=msvc-160) there is supposed to be this Color Scheme and it can be set to VS2017, as per this screenshot:

[image]

But for some reason I don't have it and I have just updated it and this what my Text Editor->C/C++->View looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks the only way to solve this problem is to change the colors one by one. But you may ask, how do I come up with colors, I'm not a graphic/UI/UX designer? Here's how. You open the colors in VS2017 in **Options->Fonts and Colors** and select **Text Editor** in **Show settings for:**, and there when you scroll down you will see the colors for all C++ keywords.

That was Step 1. In Step 2 you go to the same dialog in VS2019, and one buy one change VS2019 settings to match those of VS2019. Having two monitors or one wide monitor helps.

Here's the screenshot:

[image]